# How does erlang:now() work?

Tags: erlang, eshell

```
-module(test_now).

-compile(export_all).

start() ->  
    {_, A, _} = now(),
    loop(0, A).

loop(A) ->  
    {_, B, _} = now(),  
    if   
        B == A + 1 -> loop(0, B);  
        true -> loop(A)  
    end.  

loop(T, B) ->
    {_, C, _} = now(),
    if 
        C == B + 1 -> io:write(T);
        true -> loop(T+1, B)
    end.
```

Logically this code should run `1+` second. But the result returns rapidly, far less than one second. And if I invoke `test_now:start()` in the Eshell **frequently** (up-arrow, enter,up-arrow, enter...),  the results are always `999999ok`.

Comment: Why are doing this? Is it to test `now/0` or do you want something which just suspends a process for a fixed amount of time? If you want the latter then this is a bad way of doing it as it is a busy wait. A **much** better way is to use `timer:sleep/1`.

Comment: For generating a unique key for some db in the fastest but safe way. Actually I am comparing now() with os:timestamp().

Comment: OK, well calls to `now/0` are guaranteed to return unique values, but in worst case they can run ahead of the clock if you do many calls. It will correct itself when possible. `os:timestamp/0` is actually more efficient on a multicore system if you REALLY push like you are doing as `now/0` needs synchronisation.

Comment: The last word is REALLY enlightening. Thanks.

Comment: But for most normal use there is no problem.

Answer (score 9):

From the documentation ([now/0](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#now-0)):

> It is also guaranteed that subsequent calls to this BIF returns
>   continuously increasing   values. Hence, the return value from now()
>   can be used to generate unique time-stamps, and   if it is called in a
>   tight loop on a fast machine the time of the node can become skewed.

So you can't use [now/0](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#now-0) to check the time like in your example. You can try [os:timestamp/0](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/os.html#timestamp-0) instead:

```
start() ->  
    {_, S, MS} = os:timestamp(),
    loop(0, {S, MS}).

loop(T, {S, MS}=Start) ->
    {_, S2, MS2} = os:timestamp(),
    if 
        S2 == S + 1 andalso MS2 == MS -> io:format("~p~n", [T]);
        true -> loop(T + 1, Start)
    end.
```

Example:

```
1> timer:tc(test_timestamp, start, []).
13600591
{1000047,ok}
```

But if you just want to get some notification in one second consider to use [erlang:send_after/3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#send_after-3) or [erlang:start_timer/3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#start_timer-3):

```
start() ->  
    erlang:send_after(1000, self(), timeout),
    loop(0).

loop(T) ->
    receive
        timeout -> io:format("~p~n", [T])
    after
        0 -> loop(T + 1)
    end.
```

Example:

```
1> timer:tc(test_timer, start, []).
27433087
{1000520,ok}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I am so sorry for not stating my real purpose for my code. I was trying to generate a unique key for some db in the fastest but safe way. Actually I was comparing now() with os:timestamp(). And I had already read all the doc about timestamp() and now(). Obviously timestamp() is not suitable. Meanwhile I was afraid now() would be too slow since the documentation says "If you do not need the return value to be unique and monotonically increasing, use os:timestamp/0 instead to avoid some overhead." That is the whole story. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: For generating an unique key consider also [erlang:make_ref/0](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#make_ref-0) or [crypto:rand_bytes/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html#rand_bytes-1), [crypto:rand_uniform/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html#rand_uniform-2)

Comment: That would be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: You can actually use `erlang:now()` as a tool to get a unique id. But do note there is a lock around that call so it is not going to be fast if many cores ask for it. It is often better to use some other way. If you can live with "holes" in your Id sequences, look into creating a `gen_server` which exposes a HILO interface to workers.

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to check that the seconds component of `now/0` has increased if you want to wait for 1 second (i.e. `C == B +1` in the `if`), you also have to take the microseconds component into consideration.

In the extreme case `now() = {_, X, 999999}`, which means that the seconds component will be `X+1` in just 1 microsecond.

I have no idea why you would always get 999999 loops with this solution.

Comment: I just want to figure out the approximate times that now() can be called within one second.